# How can I add months onto a given date in a SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a function to represent when an employees (agents) 6 month review will take place, using date arithmetic by adding on 6 months to their hire date and I can't seem to get it right

```
SELECT EmpFirstName, EmpLastName,
CAST(DateHired, + 6 MONTH) AS ReviewDate
From Employees
```

Comment: Do these 6 month reviews happen repeatedly, i.e. at 6, 12, 18, etc. months?  Or, is this a one time review at 6 months after the hire date?

Comment: Just 6 months, I'm trying to do this via a date arithmetic method

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EmpFirstName, EmpLastName,DATEADD(month, 6, DateHired) DateHired From Employees
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT EmpFirstName
    ,EmpLastName
    ,DateHired

SET Datehired = DATE_ADD(DateHired, INTERVAL + 6 MONTH)
FROM Employees
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp

Answer (score 0):

With SET you can mutate the value (change the value) but what you really need is a condition to check. The SQL keyword for that is WHERE.

```
SELECT .... WHERE your conditon FROM ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DATEADD()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql)

```
SELECT EmpFirstName, EmpLastName,  DateHired, DATEADD(month, 6, DateHired) AS Review_Date 
From Employees
```

The idea of updating the `DateHired` column is not that good. Because if  you run the query at two different times, for example  be when some new employees joins, it will affect the records of all employees.

Either add a new column for `ReviewDate` in the table or use some query like the one above to  find the ReviewDate

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of all employees who are due for their 6 month review in the current month, you can try this:

```
SELECT
    EmpFirstName,
    EmpLastName,
    DateHired
FROM Employees
WHERE
    DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DateHired), 0) =
    DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())), 0)
```